# Missing Car API in AOSP Android SDK

Tags: android, android-source

I'm interested in Android Automotive. I checked out AOSP source code and successfully compiled the emulator

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_car_x86_64
make
```

and the Android SDK

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch sdk-eng
make update-car-api
make sdk
```

I'm getting an SDK in `out/host/linux-x86/sdk/sdk`. In this SDK I'm missing the **Car API** from `packages/services/Car/car-lib`. How can I compile an SDK for the car services and get a Java JAR?

Comment: I'm looking for the same.  Here's a related link but the proposed solution does not work.  https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-porting/bEum_nDUfpw

Comment: Are there any news ?